# Seemingly inconsistent exit/SIGINT behavior in bash function with sub-process

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a program `command` which reads some user input and performs something akin to a login, and errs out if the login fails either due to incorrect credentials or a lack of network connectivity.
I created a function `command-retryable` where the original version looked like this:

```bash
command-retryable()
{
  while true
  do
    command && break
  done
}
```

This accomplished the initial goal of alawys retrying `command` no matter what, but "no matter what" included `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` which was problematic as I had this command set to run on login, so if it failed unrecoverably, or if I had no internet, I effectively softlocked my terminal.

Unfortunately, `command` is not mine and is rather poorly written, with two critical flaws:

1. seemingly all failure cases cause it to exit with `1`
2. literally all output goes to `stderr`, including user prompts and success output

So I couldn't do more basic error code testing, or easily catch `stdout` for success, but it does at least produce different error messages for different failures, so a solution I came up with was to store any and all text output in a variable: `RESULT="$(command 2>&1)"` and then do manual validation against the contents of the string

```bash
command-retryable()
{
  while true
  do
    RESULT="$(command 2>&1)"
    if echo $RESULT | grep -q 'known phrase from error 1'; then
      echo "Retryable failure happened"
    elif echo $RESULT | grep -q 'known phrase from error 2'; then
      echo "Non-retryable failure happened; exiting"
      break
    else
      echo "Sanity check; command stdout: $RESULT; exiting"
      break
    fi
  done
}
```

> I realized while writing this that the echo | grep -q could be replaced with test ~=, promise I'll rewrite it that way after

The weird behavior this has introduced is, now during `command`, if I `CTRL+C` or `CTRL+Z` during the wait for user input, not only does it exit `command`, it also exits `command-retryable`, without hitting my `if else` at all.
This isn't *completely* undesirable, as I wanted to `break` on this case anyway, but I don't understand why my original implementation wouldn't exit, and this one does - or, more specifically, what "$(command 2>&1)" changes that causes `SIGINT`/`SIGKILL` to either propagate up to, or be directly received by, the parent function.
It also seems to bypass `trap`; I tried adding

```bash
trap 'echo "CAUGHT SIGINT"' SIGINT
```

after `done`, but this output doesn't appear, which would indicate to me that somehow an interrupt sent to `command` is killing `command-retryable` without actually sending that interrupt to `command-retryable`.

Comment: Putting the `trap` after the `done` in the function means that it won't be defined until you run the function AND the `while` loop exits; it's better to move it out from the function and put it before any instruction is executed

Comment: _"[...], now during command, if I `CTRL+C` or `CTRL+Z` during the wait for user input, not only does it exit `command`, it also exits `command-retryable`"_ The command that is effectively running when you hit `Ctrl-C` is now `RESULT="..."` which is a shell builtin, so it exists the shell